# Updating Repeat Items Index

Tags: angularjs

I have a collection of items which I am displaying in my view using [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). I also have two buttons, one to move the item to the left, and the other to move the item to the right.

**View**

```
<div  data-ng-repeat="item in items">

    <!--Move Item Index to the Left-->
    <a href="#">
        <i ng-click="move($index, $index - 1)" class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
    </a>
    <!--Move Item Index to the Right-->
    <a href="#" >
        <i ng-click="move($index, $index + 1)" class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </a>

    <h1>{{item.name}}</h1>

</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.move = function(fromIndex, toIndex) {
    var element = $scope.items[fromIndex];
     $scope.items.splice(fromIndex, 1);
     $scope.items.splice(toIndex, 0, element);
};
```

The array is updating but the changes are not reflected in the UI.

**How can I get the changes to reflect in the UI?**

Comment: i think it work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It is working correctly. Just add some text in the i tag and click on it.

```
<div  data-ng-repeat="item in items">

        <!--Move Item Index to the Left-->
        <a href="#">
            <i ng-click="move($index, $index - 1)" class="fa fa-chevron-left">Left</i>
        </a>
        <!--Move Item Index to the Right-->
        <a href="#" >
            <i ng-click="move($index, $index + 1)" class="fa fa-chevron-right">Right</i>
        </a>

        <h1>{{item}}</h1>

</div>
```

Comment: You're right! It turns out there was a library affecting the change. I'm using and angular version of http://masonry.desandro.com/ and this was stopping the change. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is just working, see [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mikey/36r24621/)

(I removed the css classes because no css lib available in the example)

#### index.html

```
<div id="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div data-ng-repeat="item in items">

    {{item}}

    <!--Move Item Index to the Left-->
    <a href="#" ng-click="move($index, $index - 1)">&lt;</a>
    <!--Move Item Index to the Right-->
    <a href="#" ng-click="move($index, $index + 1)">&gt;</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

#### app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

    $scope.move = function (fromIndex, toIndex) {
      var element = $scope.items[fromIndex];
      $scope.items.splice(fromIndex, 1);
      $scope.items.splice(toIndex, 0, element);
    };
  });

angular.bootstrap(document.querySelector('#app'), ['myApp']);
```

Note that you cannot move the first item back and the last item forward, because the first item already is the first of the list :).

- Don't forget to add some text (for screenreaders!) to the chevrons and it's better to set the `ng-click` on the anchors.
- `href="#"` is not necessary. You don't want to link to `#` (which usually is the landing page of your app) -> `<a href ng-click="...">`
- Even better: if you want the have a pointer cursor, you could use CSS for this: `cursor: pointer` and omit the `href`.

Comment: You're right! It turns out there was a library affecting the change. I'm using and angular version of http://masonry.desandro.com/ and this was stopping the change. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well, I created this [example on Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/TSVM7qKaJhLa889YFfFY?p=preview) and it is changing position

I just moved MOVE method to `<a>` tag.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src=".../angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="Ctrl">

  <div  data-ng-repeat="item in items">

    <!--Move Item Index to the Left-->
    <a href="#" ng-click="move($index, $index - 1)">
        <i  class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
        Left
    </a>
    <!--Move Item Index to the Right-->
    <a href="#" ng-click="move($index, $index + 1)" >
        <i  class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
        Right
    </a>

    <h1>{{item.name}}</h1>

</div>


</div>



  </body>
</html>


function Ctrl($scope) {

 $scope.items = [{name:'aa'}, {name:'bb'}, {name:'cc'},{name:'dd'}]
  console.log($scope.items)

 $scope.move = function(fromIndex, toIndex) {
    console.log($scope.items)
    var element = $scope.items[fromIndex];
     $scope.items.splice(fromIndex, 1);
     $scope.items.splice(toIndex, 0, element);

};

}
```

Comment: You're right! It turns out there was a library affecting the change. I'm using and angular version of http://masonry.desandro.com/ and this was stopping the change. Thank you